# Allocating labels to grouped values in pandas

Tags: pandas

I am producing some statistics which require grouping results by church, and only counting those churches which have been visited more than once.

So I can do:

```
df = pd.read_excel('/home/tim/metatron/church_data.xlsx')
chthresh = 1 # Minimum number of visits to a church in order to be considered

chgp = df.groupby('Church')

chcnt = pd.DataFrame(chgp['Date'].count())
chcnt2 = chcnt[chcnt['Date'] > chthresh]
```

which gives me what I want:

```
In[8]: chcnt2
Out[8]: 
            Date
Church          
Manchester    36
Sale          29
Salford       33
```

For the purposes of analysis, though, I would like to anonymise these churches and replace them with (say) A, B, C etc. (There may be more than three churches). What would be the easiest/best way to allocate some sort of alphabetic label, e.g. in this case "Manchester" -> "A", "Sale" -> "B", "Salford" -> "C"

I can give the churches some sort of ordinal value:

```
chcnt3 = chcnt2.reset_index()
chcnt3['Ordinal']=chcnt3.index.values
```

Which produces

```
In[9]: chcnt3
Out[9]: 
       Church  Date  Ordinal
0  Manchester    36        0
1        Sale    29        1
2     Salford    33        2
```

But how would I convert this to some sort of letter? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a letter map:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
letter_map = dict(zip(range(len(ascii_uppercase)), ascii_uppercase))
```

and use this for mapping:

```
chcnt3['letter'] = chcnt3['Ordinal'].map(letter_map)

chcnt3
Out: 
       Church  Date  Ordinal letter
0  Manchester    36        0      A
1        Sale    29        1      B
2     Salford    33        2      C
```

Without creating the ordinal column, you can do this on the `chcnt2` DataFrame too:

```
chcnt2['letter'] = list(ascii_uppercase[:len(chcnt2)])

chcnt2
Out: 
            Date letter
Church                 
Manchester    36      A
Sale          29      B
Salford       33      C
```